# where is the layout xml and the png's for Android Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I need to code certain Dialogs as Activities that look like dialogs. For this I would like to make them look like the standard Android dialog, esp the white adaptable frame with the round edges.

Where/how can I find this xml and png in the Android library?

Many thanks

Comment: [here is custom dialog](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-custom-dialog-tutorial.html) and you can set as per your need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show an `Activity` having the look and feel of a `Dialog` then you can add the following attribute to the concerned activity declaration in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".YOURACTIVITY"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this in manifest file:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

This will open the activity as Dialog.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct, if it is useful to you. So that others can get help.

Comment: actually this is one of these cases again where there are two answers and one can only accept one. Arun's answer had the reference to the activities name & was a little faster I assume since it was first in the list - but if I could I would accept both!